# How can I use arrow key to move up / down in a NSTableView's rows?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I want to quick move between rows using arrow key. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried this and it isn't working? As Christian notes below, it is standard functionality that should be working. If it is not, let us know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ;)

That's standard functionality.